# worker can't get new data insert to mysql in task of flask celery

Tags: python, flask, celery, celery-task, celeryd

I have three server run my program and each server have eight celery worker to get the task from the redis. That is to say each server's celery task can be execute by another server.

In each server:
**commit changes and call task**

```
    ...
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.error(str(e))
        db.session.rollback()
        if not ci_existed:  # only add
            self.delete(ci.ci_id)
        return abort(500, "add CI error")
    his_manager = CIAttributeHistoryManger()
    his_manager.add(ci.ci_id, histories)
    ci_cache.apply_async([ci.ci_id], queue="async")
    # add bj ci
    add_ci_bj.apply_async([ci_type.type_name, None, ci.ci_id], queue="async")
    return ci.ci_id
```

**task function**

```
@celery.task(name="xxxxxxx", queue="async")
def add_ci_bj(ci_type, first_id, second_id):
    param, status = lib.ci.CIManager().get_relations(first_id, second_id, is_async=True)
    ...
```

**function in task**

```
def get_relations(self, first_id, second_id, is_async=False):
    start = time.clock()
    try:
        second = self.get_ci_by_id(second_id, need_children=False)
    except Exception as e:
    return None, "get ci by id error: first %s, second %s, e %s, is_async:%s" % \
           (first_id, second_id, e, is_async)
    ...
```

I insert data and commit to MySQL and call task `add_ci_bj`, but I can't get the data by `second_id`, I can't figure out, anyone can give some help?

Comment: Hi 
Are you got solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

got the answer, close the session before call in another server. Such as:

```
@celery.task(name="xxxxxxx", queue="async")
def add_ci_bj(ci_type, first_id, second_id):
    db.session.Close()
    param, status = lib.ci.CIManager().get_relations(first_id, second_id, is_async=True)
    ...
```